# Javascript - Reduce array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Array input**: `[["test","test"],["test2","test"],["test2","test2"],["test","test2"]]`

**Array output**: `["test test","test2 test","test2 test2","test test2"]`

I'm able to obtain this output with:

```
output = input.join("|").replace(/,/g," ").toString().split("|")
```

However, I don't really like this workaround because:

- It seems unnatural
- If one of the arrays contains a *comma* itself, it    will be also
  removed
- If one of the arrays contains a *pipe* itself, the split will be not as expected

How can I get the output without those handicaps?

Comment: #FP: a generic util `var join = glue => arr => Array.prototype.join.call(Object(arr), glue);` and it's usage `arr.map( join(" ") );` works on anything that looks like an Array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of joining the outer array, you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) each inner array separately:

```
var arr = [["test","test"],["test2","test"],["test2","test2"],["test","test2"]];
var output = arr.map(subarr => subarr.join(' '));
```

Comment: It works perfect, thx. Thanks also for the map method. It looks really powerfull.